# apache: how to redirect one HTTPS TLD to another HTTPS TLD of the same domain

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, redirect

I have 3 domains: domain.com, domain.org, and domain.net
I have an SSL cert for .org, but not .com and .net.
I would rather not have to purchase SSL certs for all 3 TLDs.
How do I redirect the .com and .net domains to .org ?
Normal HTTP apache redirection methods don't seem to be working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want HTTPS connections to not get an error, you need a HTTPS certificate for that connection.  What is unclear about this?

Comment: so I can't redirect one https to another?

Comment: Did you buy / obtain certificates since I answered the question the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to provide HTTPS service on a domain -- even if you're just going to be providing a redirect -- you need an SSL certificate for that domain. There is no way around this.

So, you basically have two options:

- Get SSL certificates for all your domains. If cost is a concern, keep in mind that [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) will issue certificates for free, no strings attached.
- Don't provide HTTPS service on the extra domains -- provide the redirect as HTTP only. If you've never provided HTTPS service on these domains before, this is probably fine -- nobody is likely to try to load them over HTTPS, and there isn't anything on those domains that needs to be encrypted.